Fine-Tuning with Custom Dataset: Formatting and Best Practices
I’m working on a domain-specific problem where no pre-existing datasets are available. I’ve manually collected some examples and initially used them in Large Language Model (LLM) prompts (few-shot learning). However, the results are not very good, and i am doing fine-tuning for better outcomes.
I’ve created my own dataset for fine-tuning a Large Language Model (LLM). The goal is for the model to take a simple text input and output two Python lists: one with what the user is looking for and the other with what the user is not looking for. For example:
Input:
"I am looking for a laptop with a good camera and long battery life, but I don’t want any laptops that use only USB-C."

Output:
wants : ["laptop", "camera", "long battery life"]
does not want: ["does not want laptop that uses USB-C"]

Currently, my dataset consists of two columns—input and output. However, I’m still unsure how to format the dataset going forward. Should I use multiple columns, or is there a better approach? I’ve noticed that some datasets have multiple outputs, and I’m curious about why they do that and whether I should adopt a similar structure.
here are some other questions i have and it would be great if some people could answer it:

What types of data are most beneficial as input for this type of
task (e.g., raw text, structured data)?
Best practices for preparing and formatting data for fine-tuning?
How should I format my dataset to make it more effective for
fine-tuning?
Any best practices for preparing and scaling up my dataset for better results?
Any tutorials or tools that can help streamline the fine-tuning
process for a text-and-logic generation problem.

Any tips, insights, or references to useful resources would be greatly appreciated!
